# Solr partial search

Tags: solr, full-text-search

(Solr newbie here) I setup a simple solr instance to index a collection of html/pdf documents. It basically works but I'm stuck trying to add a *partial search* functionality.

What I tried so far:
Since I think it's better keeping the default managed schema, I tried using the schema api to add a field `text_partial` with an *ngram* filter, like that.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
"add-field-type":{
    "name":"text_ngram",
    "class":"solr.TextField",
    "positionIncrementGap":"100",
    "indexAnalyzer":{
        "tokenizer":{
        "class":"solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"
        },
        "filters": [
            {"class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"},
            {
            "class":"solr.NGramTokenizerFactory",
            "maxGramSize":"25",
            "minGramSize":"3",
            }
        ]

    },
    "queryAnalyzer":{
      "tokenizer":{
        "class":"solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"},
      "filters":[
        {"class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"}]}
},
"add-field":{
    "name": "text_partial",
    "type": "text_ngram",
    "indexed": true,
    "stored": true
}
}' http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/my_collection/schema
```

I tried to delete all documents and reindex, but I cant see any difference from before: full word searching still works but a query for "text_partial:something" gives no results.

Then I realized I did not make any modification to my DataImportHandler, that is currently like that

```
<dataConfig>  
    <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" />
        <document>
            <entity name="files" dataSource="null" rootEntity="false"
            processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
            baseDir="C:/xampp/htdocs/tcdocs12" fileName=".*\.(html|pdf)"
            onError="skip"
            recursive="true">
                <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="id" />
                <field column="fileSize" name="size" />
                <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastModified" />

                <entity
                    name="documentImport"
                    processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
                    url="${files.fileAbsolutePath}"
                    format="text"
                    transformer="TemplateTransformer,RegexTransformer"
                    >
                    <field column="file" name="fileName"/>
                    <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
                    <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
                    <field column="text" name="text"/>

                    <field column="tempCol" template="${files.fileAbsolutePath}" regex="${dataimporter.request.docs_dir}(.*)" replaceWith="$1"/>

                    <field column="url" regex="\\" replaceWith="/" sourceColName="tempCol"/>
                    <field column="cat" regex="^\/.+?\/(.+?)\/.*" replaceWith="$1" sourceColName="url"/>


                </entity>
        </entity>
        </document> 
</dataConfig>
```

Do I have to make any modification to the DIH or schema in order to have "the document text content" also processed and indexed in the "text_partial" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is not added to fields magically. If you already have the content indexed into a field such as the one named `text`, you can add a `copyField` instruction to effectively index the same content into two fields with different processing.

See [Add a new copy field rule in the Schema API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html#SchemaAPI-AddaNewCopyFieldRule):

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-copy-field":{
     "source":"text",
     "dest":[ "text_partial" ]}
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection/schema
```

You'll need to reindex after you've added this rule, since the copying happens before any further processing when indexing.